# Passing a Php Variable Through Ajax to Update a Frame

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a server-side PHP page that draws data from an SQL database to populate an array of PHP variables.  I use the last array value for each variable to initially populate the data into the 3rd frame of a form (i.e., value = ).  This form has a "previous" and "next" link that I want to use to populate the 3rd frame of the form with the "previous" or "next" set of variable values (i.e., value = ) dynamically without loading the entire page.  While I'm very familiar with javascript, php and sql this will be the first time I've tried to use AJAX.  What I'm trying to do is pass the array number or counter, which is a php variable, to an AJAX function which increases or decreases the array counter (i.e., $counter) so that the values for the next set of variables appears in frame 3 of the form.  My problem is that I'm sure that I can pass the current $counter value to the AJAX function which will process it as a javascript variable but how can I then pass the result back to update the php variable in frame 3 of the form?  Any help will be very much appreciated.

Blacksquare:

My php web page does the first part. It gathers data from the underlying SQL database and places it into a php array.  When the web page initially loads, the most recent or last record is used to populate the form fields that are all in a single frame using something like this (value=$dataField[$counter]).  This works when the page is initially loaded populating all of the frame fields with data from the last record in the SQL database.  What I'm trying to do is create an AJAX function activated by clicking on the "next" or "previous" link (i.e., an onclick event) that takes the $counter value and increases or decreases it by one (1) and then refreshes the frame displaying fields from the "next" or "previous" php array record in the same frame without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a php file which will handle the ajax request (passing the variable as post parameter) and echo your response in the php file.

Then in ajax file you will get response in success, update the response using jQuery into the form.

Note: Don't forget to put 'exit' after the response in php file.

For example:

```
$.post( "test.php", { counter: <?php echo $counter; ?>}).done(function( data ) { alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about altering appropriate HTML elements using JavaScript after you get results of the ajax call? There is no need to set the php variable and then to use that field to set a value in HTML when you can alter that HTML value directly from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a variable back into a static page generated by php. Probably the best approach is to load only the form on page load. Then grab the dynamic data using an ajax call to another php script on the server side (I'm using jQuery for the ajax).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: someURL, //A link to your php script that will load the data  
    dataType: "json" //Ask for json data from the server
}).done(function(data) {
    nextRecords = data;
    getNextRecord();
}).fail(function(resp) {
    console.log("Something Went Wrong");
});
```

Move your sql logic to a separate php script accessed at someURL and have php pass back an array of json data like this

```
$query = ...Your select query returning an array of results
echo json_encode($query);
exit;
```

Now when a user hits the next/previous button, you can easily grab the latest record without posting to the server.

```
function getNextRecord() {
    if (nextRecords.length > 0) {
        var record = nextRecords.pop();
        var node = document.getElementById(node_name);
        node.innerHTML = record;
        if (currentRecord){             
            prevRecords.push(currentRecord);
        }
        currentRecord = record;
    }
}

function getPreviousRecord() {
    if (prevRecords.length > 0) {
        var record = prevRecords.pop();
        var node = document.getElementById(node_name);
        node.innerHTML = record;
        if (currentRecord) {             
            nextRecords.push(currentRecord);
        }
        currentRecord = record;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Blacksquare - I've edited my original question seeking additional information about your response.  Please see above.

Comment: I see what your issue is. Try this--instead of loading the first record server side. Load only the form in php then load all the data at once via ajax. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm sure that is the answer.  I just need to work with it for a while to make it work with my application.  Thanks Blacksquare!